# Monaco-editor: How do I disable just the syntax validation?

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to use the language highlighting but I don't want to use the syntax validation.

I have a different validation server so I don't want to show the error underlines on the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Example for JSON:

```
        monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
            validate: false
        });
```

Comment: How to disable for all languages? Looks like it's only disable for json

Comment: I thought so too. I tried it and it disabled errors in all languages for me. Not sure if it makes sense though.